# Formatting html tags in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I am reading an data from an XML file for my iPhone application. This data contains html tags such as `<p></p> <strong> <B>`, etc in it. By using NSString class can i remove these tags and format the display of the text as needed.

For example, if text inside the `<p> </p>` i want to display it in next paragraph. Is it possible?

Please suggest.

Any help would be appreciated.

-Sathiya

Answer (score 1):

Why not leave the formatting in place, and use either a UIWebView to display the text or a `TTStyledTextLabel` from the [Three20](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20) project.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm... Only me doesn't see an example? But you can insert @"\n" to move text to the next line in your UITextView or console.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library on the iPhone to do HTML parsing, but it takes a bit more work than using NSString. However, it will give you a lot more control. You can walk the HTML tree and pick out the parts that interest you.

Look at libxml2's html reader:

http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html#htmlReadMemory